# How to handle errors in Gin middleware

Tags: go, error-handling, go-gin

I want to grab all http errors on each route without rewrite each time if 400 then if 404 then if 500 then etc... so I have an `ErrorHandler()` function inside each route handler:

```
func (h *Handler) List(c *gin.Context) {
    movies, err := h.service.ListService()

    if err != nil {
        utils.ErrorHandler(c, err)
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, movies)
}
```

This function look like this:

```
func ErrorHandler(c *gin.Context, err error) {
    if err == ErrNotFound {
        // 404
        c.JSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"error": ErrNotFound.Error()})
    } else if err == ErrInternalServerError {
        // 500
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": ErrInternalServerError.Error()})
    } // etc...
}
```

`ErrNotFound` or `ErrInternalServerError` are just global variables initialized like this :

```
var ErrNotFound = errors.New(http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound))  // 404
```

I'd like to know if I'm doing right or if there is a better way to do this like grab the error inside the middleware and return directly the response ?

With node.js I was able to send `err` in the middleware parameter and use it like this:

```
app.use((err: any, req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    if (err instanceof HttpError) {
        res.status(err.status).json({error: err.message});
      } else if (err instanceof Error) {
        res.status(500).json({error: err.message});
      } else {
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      }
});
```

There is something similar ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

More idiomatic than using a function (`utils` is also frowned upon as a package name) is using a middleware:

```
func ErrorHandler(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()

        for _, err := range c.Errors {
            // log, handle, etc.
        }
    
        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, "")
}


func main() {
    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(middleware.ErrorHandler)
    // ... routes
}
```

Notably, you call [`c.Next()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Next) inside the middleware func **before** your actual error handling code, so you make sure the error handling happens after the rest of the handler chain has been called.

> Next should be used only inside middleware. It executes the pending handlers in the chain inside the calling handler. [...]

The advantage of using a middleware is that you can also pass arguments to it, e.g. a logger, that you may want to use later as part of the error handling, *once*, instead of passing it every time you call `utils.ErrorHandler` directly. In this case it looks like this (I use Uber Zap loggers):

```
func ErrorHandler(logger *zap.Logger) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()
        
        for _, ginErr := range c.Errors {
            logger.Error("whoops", ...)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    router := gin.New()
    
    logger, _ := zap.NewDevelopment()

    router.Use(middleware.ErrorHandler(logger))
    // ... routes
}
```

The handlers then will just abort the chain, instead of calling a function, which looks cleaner and it's easier to maintain:

```
func (h *Handler) List(c *gin.Context) {
    movies, err := h.service.ListService()

    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithError(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
        return
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, movies)
}
```

It's important to note that if you set an HTTP status in `c.AbortWithStatus` or `c.AbortWithError`, you may want to **not** overwrite it in the error handler. In that case, you can call `c.JSON()` with `-1` as status code:

```
func ErrorHandler(logger *zap.Logger) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()
        
        for _, ginErr := range c.Errors {
            logger.Error("whoops", ...)
        }

        // status -1 doesn't overwrite existing status code
        c.JSON(-1, /* error payload */)
    }
}
```

Lastly, using a middleware allows you to call [`c.Error`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Error) in your handlers multiple times, e.g. when a series of non-fatal errors occur and you want to capture all of them before actually aborting the request.

> Error attaches an error to the current context. The error is pushed to a list of errors. It's a good idea to call Error for each error that occurred during the resolution of a request. A middleware can be used to collect all the errors and [process them]

```
func (h *Handler) List(c *gin.Context) {
    err1 := /* non-fatal error */
    if err1 != nil {
        c.Error(err1)
    }

    err2 := /* another non-fatal error */
    if err2 != nil {
        c.Error(err2)
    }

    fatalErr := /* fatal error */
    if fatalErr != nil {
        c.AbortWithError(505, fatalErr)
        return
        // the error handler will have collected all 3 errors
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, movies)
}
```

---

As for the actual error handling in the middleware, it's pretty straightforward. Just remember that all calls to `c.Error`, `c.AbortWith...` will wrap your error in a [`gin.Error`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Error). So to inspect the original value you have to check the `err.Err` field:

```
func ErrorHandler(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()

        for _, err := range c.Errors {
            switch err.Err {
                case ErrNotFound:
                  c.JSON(-1, gin.H{"error": ErrNotFound.Error()})  
            }
            // etc...
        }

        c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, "")
}
```

Iterating over `c.Errors` may seem unwieldy because now you have potentially N errors instead of one, but depending on how you intend to use the middleware, you can simply check `len(c.Errors) > 0` and access only the first item `c.Errors[0]`.

Comment: Will the error being returned in the response be removed in the c.Errors automatically?

Comment: @jmsandiegoo `c` is request scoped, so at the end of the middleware chain that context ceases to exist and errors are cleared.

Comment: If you are asking whether handler errors are stored in `c.Errors` automatically, then no, you have to call some function on `c` that takes also error arguments to propagate errors

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of handling errors in middleware is handling errors centralized, as opposed to explicitly handling exceptions in each handler.

In order to reduce mapping errors to response, my project 
[gin-error](https://github.com/richzw/gin-error) is one middleware for error handling.

```golang
func Error(errM ...*ErrorMap) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()

        lastError := c.Errors.Last()
        if lastError == nil {
            return
        }

        for _, err := range errM {
            for _, e := range err.errors {
                if e == lastError.Err || errors.Is(e, lastError.Err) {
                    err.response(c)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Usage Sample:

- You can map the error to one status code

```golang
import (
    "github.com/richzw/gin-error"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
var BadRequestErr = fmt.Errorf("bad request error")

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(err.Error(err.NewErrMap(BadRequestErr).StatusCode(http.StatusBadRequest)))

    r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Error(BadRequestErr)
    })

    r.Run()
}
```

- Or map error to one response

```golang
import (
    "github.com/richzw/gin-error"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)
var BadRequestErr = fmt.Errorf("bad request error")

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.Use(err.Error(
        err.NewErrMap(BadRequestErr).Response(func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"error": BadRequestErr.Error()})
        })))

    r.GET("/test", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Error(BadRequestErr)
    })

    r.Run()
}
```